# Matching a variable in order to pull value from an array

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-array

The script will echo the different values stored in an array based on user input. However, the output is not correct and the wrong value is echoed.

```
AA_P=/root/run_Scripts/AA_P_run.sh
AA_S=/root/run_Scripts/AA_S_run.sh

read -p "Enter 'P' or 'S'"$'\n' P_S

read -p "How many runs?"$'\n' runs

script="AA${P_S}"
echo $script

echo ""
declare -A Arr=( [AAP]=$AA_P [AAS]=$AA_S )

for key in ${Arr[@]}; do
    if [[ $key == $nScript ]]; then
        key="${Arr[$key]}"
    fi

    while [ $runs -gt 0 ]; do
        echo $key 
        (( runs=runs-1 ))
    done
done
exit
```

When input is 'S' and '3', the output is as follows.

```
AAS

/root/run_Scripts/AA_P_run.sh
/root/run_Scripts/AA_P_run.sh
/root/run_Scripts/AA_P_run.sh
```

Why is the script not echoing '/root/run_Scripts/**AA_S_run.sh**?

Comment: It was a mistake, Script should be nScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${assoc[@]}` expands to the *values* of the associative array (subject to split+glob as you forgot the quotes around it). For the list of *keys*, you need `"${!assoc[@]}"` in `bash` like in ksh93 whose syntax `bash` copied¹.

Also, why loop over the keys until you find the one? Just do:

```
while ((runs--)); do
 printf '%s\n' "${Arr[$nScript]}"
done
```

Other notes:

- if you want to check that `$nScript` is amongst the keys of the array, you can do: `if [[ -n $nScript && -n ${Arr[$nScript]+set} ]]; then...` (the additional test for `$nScript` being non-empty to work around the fact that `bash` associative arrays choke on empty keys).
- `$nScript` doesn't appear to be set in your script (`$script` is)
- `[[ $a == $b ]]` tests whether the `$a` variable matches the pattern stored in `$b` in `bash` (like in `ksh` where that `[[...]]` construct comes from). If you wanted to check whether `$a` and `$b` are identical, you'd need `[[ $a == "$b" ]]`.

---

<sup>¹ had it copied zsh's syntax instead, that would have been `"${(k@)assoc}"` instead.</sup>

Comment: Can you explain adding '&&' with '+set' instead of simply using '=='?